# Bottom Tab Navigator: 'tabBarOptions' is deprecated. Migrate the options to 'screenOptions' instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native app.

and I have some navigation functionality. And everything works fine. But Every time the app starts. I get this warning:

```
Bottom Tab Navigator: 'tabBarOptions' is deprecated. Migrate the options to 'screenOptions' instead.
```

And this is my component:

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const TAB_ICON = {
    Dieren: "md-paw",
    Favorieten: "md-heart",
    Settings: "md-settings",
};

const Settings = () => (
    <SafeArea>
        <Text>Settings</Text>
    </SafeArea>
);

const createScreenOptions = ({ route }) => {
    const iconName = TAB_ICON[route.name];
    return {
        tabBarIcon: ({ size, color }) => <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />,
    };
};

export const AppNavigator = () => (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator
            screenOptions={createScreenOptions}
            tabBarOptions={{
                tabBarActiveTintColor: "tomato",
                tabBarInactiveTintColor: "green",
                tabBarStyle: [
                    {
                        display: "flex",
                    },
                    null,
                ],
            }}>
            <Tab.Screen name="Dieren" component={CategoryNavigator} />
            {/* <Tab.Screen name="Favorieten" component={CategoryNavigator} />
             */}
            <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
);
```

Question: How to suppress this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove the `tabBarOptions` property from the `Tab.Navigator` and move the options to the `screenOptions` property.

```js
const createScreenOptions = ({ route }) => {
    const iconName = TAB_ICON[route.name];
    return {
        tabBarIcon: ({ size, color }) => <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />,
        tabBarActiveTintColor: "tomato",
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: "green",
        tabBarStyle: [
            {
                display: "flex",
            },
            null,
        ],
    };
};

<Tab.Navigator screenOptions={createScreenOptions}>
 ...
</Tab.Navigator>
```